# Accessing id in a just built object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app where I have clusters and users in a belongs_to has_many relationship.

In the cluster_controller create method I write:

```
@cluster = @current_user.clusters.build(params[:cluster])
```

now I want to run some commandline script:

```
output = `echo cluster#{@cluster.id} > /tmp/out`
```

...rest of function here

I also tried

```
output = `echo cluster#{@cluster.id.to_s} > /tmp/out`
```

When I do this the file has just cluster in it and not cluster#. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `build` method initializes a new ActiveRecord object, but does not persist it to the database; generally, the `id` attribute is only set once the record has been saved (assuming it's a standard autoincrement primary key).  You probably want to use `create` rather than `build`.

Comment: Thanks, heres the issue:

The script might fail in which case I don't want to create the cluster. Should I just remove it from the database or is there a better way?

Comment: You could do the create in a transaction, then roll the transaction back if the script fails.  Another option would be to output some other identifying characteristic rather than id to the log - it really depends on your use case.

Comment: I just need to submit a unique value for each time I run the script which is run each time I create a cluster. I chose the id because it must be unique. Then if the script fails for whatever reason I should just redirect the user to the home page (or wherever) and let them know their cluster create failed. This of course should make no changes to the database.

Comment: Maybe a UUID would be a good way to go - you could use http://uuidtools.rubyforge.org/ or a similar library to generate them.